# Apple guidelines for networking application

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm designing a networking model-based IOS9 app and I'm just working on the design of the contacts tab, with UItableviewCells including UIImageView to show the profile picture of the users, Labels to show the name and the status and action buttons, and I would like to know if I have to set an standard size or standard constraints for these elements. I hope it's clear

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ For your app to be approved it will have to somewhat follow human interface guidelines at that link.

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey question edited

Comment: How is the fact that your app is a "networking model-based iOS 9 app" relevant to your question? You really need to clarify what your actual question is. At the moment it's vague and unclear.

Comment: Do what works and looks good.